# how to redraw only one specific layer ? (IOS,SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, calayer

I have my `UIView`. I draw something in my `UIView`. I added a `CALayer` to my `UIView`. Now I would like my controller to only redraw my added CALayer.

How do I do that ?

In my actual Code it will redraw the main view. How can I redraw my subview (myshapelayer) ?

```
     override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

            var myshapelayer:CAShapeLayer=CAShapeLayer();
            var testbezier:UIBezierPath=UIBezierPath();
            testbezier.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 60, y: 80));
            ...
    ...

            myshapelayer.strokeColor=UIColor.blueColor().CGColor;
            myshapelayer.path=testbezier.CGPath;
            newlayer.addSublayer(myshapelayer)

<draw on my main view>
```

Controller:

```
myview.setNeedsDisplay();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two ways.

First, you make delegate protocol and pass your `CALayer` to change in `ViewController`

Second, you can get `CALayer` by using `self.view.subviews` 
if `CALayer`'s index is 1, you can get `CALayer` object by `self.view.subviews[1] as? CALayer`

Hope that it may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

you can call

```
self.view.displayLayer(myshapelayer)
```

from ViewController