# How can I redraw my layer (CAShapeLayer) that is on top of a UIView after the change of rotation in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, calayer

I am trying to create charts that are being generated from the values I am getting from JSON. I am putting them on layers and adding them onto my views as sublayers. The problem is that after the change of orientation (or after( or during) the pinch and zoom (inside UIScrollView)), the graph is not redrawn according to the newly modified uiview (I have applied auto layout).
I am trying different ways to see how I can implement it and I see that while shapes drawn in that view are being resized and modified after the orientation but not the layers added to it.

In the code below, I have added one subview (containing red rectangle) and one layer(containing one diagonal to the inside rectangle) added to my charts view uiview.

```
class ChartView: UIView {
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let h = rect.height
    let w = rect.width
    var color:UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    var drect = CGRect(x: (w * 0.25),y: (h * 0.25),width: (w * 0.5),height: (h * 0.5))
    var bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: drect)
    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (w * 0.1),y: (h * 0.1),width: (w * 0.2),height: (h * 0.2)))
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.addSubview(view1)
    var gridPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(gridPath, nil, (w * 0.25), (h * 0.25))
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(gridPath, nil, (w * 0.25) + (w * 0.5), (h * 0.25) + (h * 0.5))
    layer.path = gridPath
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    color.set()
    bpath.stroke()
    }
}
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538662/how-to-redraw-only-one-specific-layer-ios-swift) involving similar issue but since I am new to this field I am not able to understand it quite fully as how to implement and where to implement.
[image and its behavior after orientation change and expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh9c6.jpg)

Comment: You (and the question you linked to) are both doing this wrong. You should not be adding views and layers in drawRect. Either draw everything in this method using paths, or add shape layers somewhere else and they will draw themselves.

Comment: thanks @jrturton I found the mistake and I corrected it. You are right that layers can be drawn outside and and they'll draw themselves.